How to setup 2 optional relations on a prisma model on top of a postgresql db
my team is trying to use a common table to store some shared information, and we would ideally have optional relations using common fields to relate the this table's records to other table records that are the shared parents of these records.
For example, say I have a model like this
model ChildId {
  commonId          Int                  @map("common_id")
  childIdType      EnumType                  @map("child_id_type")
  value            String?              @db.VarChar(64)

  entity_1           EntityType1?               @relation(fields: [commonId], references: [commonId], map: "entity_type_1_fkey")
  entity_2           EntityType2?              @relation(fields: [commonId], references: [commonId], map: "entity_type_2_fkey")

  @@id([childIdType, commonId])
  @@map("child_id")
}

When we attempt to create a record for this table, but only have a corresponding Entity1 or 2 record associated with the commonId (which is to be expected for our purposes), while the other doesn't exist, we get a foreign key error because the other entity record does not exist. For context, each Entity1 and Entity2 would have several ChildIds associated with them, so we would want 2 x 1:many relations, but we aren't guaranteed to have them. In a perfect world, these pieces of information would be represented the same way in our code base, but we simply don't have the time or permission to make that change :/
I was wondering if anyone has a nice looking solution to this, as I would absolutely love to simply use the relations we setup to make queries easier, rather than raw queries and joins everywhere we need to gather these
  const entity1 = await db.entity1.findFirst({
    where: { id: { equals: input.id } },
    include: {
      childIds: true,
    },
  });

It is safe to assume that these pieces of info will need to remain the same, I just want to do everything I can to avoid creating 2 tables which store identical information
